# Wolframscript - no output from command when exec'd from php

Tags: scripting

I am trying to run a simple command via php:

`echo shell_exec('wolframscript -code 2+2');`

However, I am unable to get any output from this command when run like this. If I just write the same thing in cmd/powershell, it works correctly.

I'm using v12, on Windows, php7.3.

Comment: Try redirecting the output like `echo shell_exec('wolframscript -code 2+2 2>&1');` or using the full path to `wolframscript`. I'm not on Windows so I can't help much further unfortunately.

Comment: None of these help. I simply get no output. Literally, `null`. Oh, the `$ret` value of `exec()` is 0. If I would have bungled the path, it would have exited with a different code (e.g. 1).

Comment: Yes, I agree that it would have done that. Have you tried [this solution?](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#88052)

Comment: Yes, though it would need to be modified - the call should be `ob_end_flush()`, not `clean` so we get the buffer rather than erasing it. Still, doesn't help though.

Comment: Very strange! As a terrible stopgap, I wonder if you could write the output to a temporary file and read it back out of that.

Comment: There... is no output. That's the problem. I tried all manner of squirrely methods, executing explicitly through cmd, executing a batch file, writing to file. E.g. stuff like `exec('cmd /c command.bat > out.txt', $output, $ret);` It won't work.

Comment: I mean writing the output within the wolframscript code, rather than shell redirection, and reading that output from the file the script wrote.

Comment: Oh... that's not actually a bad idea. I can't test it immediately though.